# Should I set the Content-Type header for a MultipartEntity?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've got a small piece of code which submits an XML entity along with binary data in the same POST. I'm using the **httpclient** and **httpmime** for this.

I'm not quite sure if I should set the `Content-Type` header for this request. After all, the `Content-Type` is both `application/xml` and `application/octet-stream`.

What's the correct usage for this?

```
    post = new HttpPost(uri);
    post.setHeader("Authorization", auth);

    // Should I set Content-Type at all?
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType + ";charset=UTF-8");

    MultipartEntityBuilder b = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    b.addTextBody("data", payload, ContentType.APPLICATION_XML);
    b.addBinaryBody("file", file);
    post.setEntity(b.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not. You should let HttpClient generate `Content-Type` as well as other content metadata headers automatically based on properties of the message entity.

Comment: Thanks! I assume this answer only applies when we're talking about a multipart body? If the body was a simple StringEntity, I would surely have to declare if it is XML, JSON or something else.

Comment: No, the same principle equally applies to all entities. For instance, one really should specify the type of content when creating StringEntity with ContentType parameter.

Comment: So what this means is that I should never interact with the Content-Type header on the request itself - but only set content type via the constructor for e.g. StringEntity? This very constructor will not allow me to set both character set and content type though.

Comment: StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("stuff", ContentType.create("text/plain", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Comment: StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("stuff", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.withCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));